# How manage data classes with empty data in retrofit?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, data-class

I want to send to the API only the data that I indicate in my data class.

```
data class UserRequestDTO(
    val name: String = "",
    val surname: String = ""
)
```

My empty class

```
val userDTO = UserRequestDTO()
MyService.getService().users()
```

My request

```
@POST("/vo/search")
    fun users(
        @Body userRequestDTO: UserRequestDTO
    ): Call<ResponseDTO>
```

But the following json is being sent:

```
{"name": "", "surname": ""}
```

How can I have a class in which I only send the data that I fill in?  don't want any data to be sent, and if for example I fill in the name, I don't want the last name to be sent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making them optional should result in not sending them:

```
data class UserRequestDTO(
    val name: String? = null,
    val surname: String? = null
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I was using class Builder and it works fine, but your option is better